# How to stream output of system process in Ruby rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a ruby rake task programated to run every night. And I want to enter to my activeadmin and see the result from this task and also run it manually.

Comment: Not quite understand. You want to catch the Ruby rake ouput, and display it in activeadmin?

Comment: yes I want to do this